# Reading an existing mongo database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I have to read an existing mongo database. Is mongoid suitable for this?

All the tutorials I found were about building a mongo database from scratch.

I have tried accessing the database using mongoid, and have no luck displaying existing information, this is what I tried.

mongoid.yml:

```
development:
  host: localhost
  database: managementdb

test:
  host: localhost
  database: managementdb
```

I did a scaffold (I don't like how mongoid takes over scaffolding)

the model:

```
class GamerProfile
  include Mongoid::Document
  store_in :profile

  field :facebookId, :type => String
  field :playerName, :type => String
  field :locale, :type => String
  field :dateJoined, :type => Time
end
```

But the existing information in localhost:27017/managementdb/Profile isn't displaying in the view.

I only need readonly access. Would mongomapper or mongomodel be more suited?

Comment: Do you mean "Is Mongoid suitable for this?"?

Comment: yeah That's what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried mongomapper after having tried mongoid, and it does exactly what it's name implies.

Let say I have a collection called `User` in mongodb which relates to a user in a game but doesn't necessarily relate to the `User` model for that application then I use `set_collection_name "User"` in a model called `GameUser` for example.

My initialiser is lifted straight from the mongodb docs; which use mongomapper for their example.

```
MongoMapper.connection = Mongo::Connection.new('localhost', 27017)
MongoMapper.database = "gamedb"
```

And my model looks like this:

```
class GameUser
  include MongoMapper::Document

  set_collection_name "User"
  key :playerName, :type => String
  ...
  key :dateJoined, :type => Time
end
```

And now my scaffold loads to data from the `GameUser` perfectly.

Comment: In case that you have a model that has a different name as the collection name in mongodb, you can do `set_collection_name "foo"`

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what the existing database contains and what you want to do with it. If it just contains some raw data that isn't specific to Rails, you can use the [generic ruby driver](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center#RubyLanguageCenter-RubyDriver) to do raw queries to the database.

If the database was created with Rails and is supposed to represent models and other Rails objects, you should use the [object mapper](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Ruby+Language+Center#RubyLanguageCenter-ObjectMappers) it was created with (I doubt this is the case).

Comment: It's raw data built by another framework in another language, but I still want to have the model and controllers for it, I just won't have any destroy actions using mongo (i have to use a rest api for destruction).

Comment: @JosephLeBrech In that case your best bet is probably to research how that framework uses the database and what is the structure of the database. This may not be simple task. Then write your raw queries to get to the data that you need (and possibly map the data so some objects as needed). Can't you use the REST API to get the data also, might make things simpler for you.

Comment: I only need to access one collection at a time, I would have thought that the models would map directly to collection. I trying with mongomapper, otherwise I might have to try an do it from scratch.

Comment: I believe the mappers are designed to create objects in the collection based on given models, not the other way around.

Comment: I've tried mongomapper and it looks like it's the solution, check my own answer XD